# what is differrence between jquery.js and jquery tools.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

can anybody explain what is the difference between them and In what situation we use the particular js file

Comment: One thing to keep in mind about jQuery tools is that it hasn't been very well maintained since jquery 1.4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery tool is an UI library, and jQuery is DOM manipulation tool. you cannot compare both. but you can compare jQuery tool and jQuery UI. both are based on jQuery framework. jQuery tool is more light weight than jQuery UI. but based on the situation it is depends. so simply don't compare as products. think about your requirement and then find what is suitable for your work.

Answer (score 1):

Tools.js is a UI framework similar to jquery ui, however it comes with jquery pre-included in it. If you include jquery tools.js, you dont need to include jquery.